# Replace img src with js jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, src

I have a newsfeed in my CMS that pulls preview images as well as teaser text for the feed.  The images are all thumbnails @ 75x75px.  I wanted to have the preview images much larger, but cannot scale an image that small.

I'm wondering what JS I need to run to replace all the URL's to the original image src.

Have:

[image: Observed]

Need to change them all to the below - which is just replacing 'thumb' with 'large':

[image: Expected]

This needs to apply to a whole css class; as it is a newsfeed & there will be new articles

Here's where I'm at:

```
function replaceImgSrc(img,imgTwo) {
var arr=[img,imgTwo];
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++) 
    arr[i].each(
        function(i,e) {
            theImg=$(this),
            theImg.attr("src", 
                function(i,e) {
                    return e.replace("_thumb","_large")
                }
            )
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: And what's the problem with your code?

Comment: That's what I'm wondering...ha.  I have to add the JS into a coding element in the CMS and use <script> </script> and it doesn't end up changing the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the newsfeed is wrapped in a class, try this way.

```
function replaceImg($class) {
    $class.find("img").each(function(k, el) {
        var newSrc = $(el).attr("src").replace("_thumb", "_large");
        $(el).attr("src", newSrc);
    });
}

replaceImg($("#newsfeed"));
```

And in your HTML, wrap the newsfeed code inside an identifiable DIV.

```
<div id="newsfeed"> {{place newsfeed code in here}} </div>
```

Comment: This seems really close.  Here's the class string:  '.expanded .newsItemHeader > a img'

Maybe you can help if I put it in reference: http://www.prepforce.com.prod.sportngin.com/contact

Comment: Instead of replaceImg($(".your-newsfeed-class")); change the selector inside that call to .expanded.

Or alternatively, within your HTML, wrap the newsfeed widget inside something like <div id="newsfeed">, and then call the function with $("#newsfeed") Doing it that way might be easiest and most failsafe - and I've changed my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this fiddle [jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/wkh6da93/](https://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/wkh6da93/)

This will find all images in page and change its src with large image.

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
    $("#btnLarge").click(function(){
    $("img").each(function(){
        var src=$(this).attr("src");
      src=src.replace("_thumb","_large");
      var src=$(this).attr("src",src);
    });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the assumption is that you have all `img` elements in an array `var imgArray`, then you can iterate thru them and update the `src` attribute like this:

```
imgArray.forEach(enlargeImageSrc);

function enlargeImageSrc (image) {
  image.src = image.src.replace('_thumb', '_large');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this hovering over the button will make the images with class="show" bigger, as soon as you remove the mouse they are small again.

```js
$("button").mouseenter(function (){
  var srcI = $(".show").attr("src");
  srcI = srcI.replace("thumb","large");
  $(".show").attr("src",srcI);
});
$("button").mouseleave(function (){
  var srcI = $(".show").attr("src");
  srcI = srcI.replace("large","thumb");
  $(".show").attr("src",srcI);
});
```

```css
button{
  display:block;
}
img.show{
  max-width:400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <button>Click me</button>
  <img class="show" src="http://cdn4.sportngin.com/attachments/news_article/7560/0742/Screen_Shot_2017-01-04_at_11.30.31_AM_thumb.png"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I make a code for you where I take two variables one for large image URL and one for small image URL. I create a function on click on change image button your image url change to big image and it show you big image and then you again click on that button it change big image to small image. You can also see the live demo of this here https://jsfiddle.net/Arsh_kalsi01/3s1uudhe/2/

```js
 

   $(document).ready(function(){
var big_image = "http://cdn4.sportngin.com/attachments/news_article/7560/0742/Screen_Shot_2017-01-04_at_11.30.31_AM_large.png";

var small_image = "http://cdn4.sportngin.com/attachments/news_article/7560/0742/Screen_Shot_2017-01-04_at_11.30.31_AM_thumb.png";


 $(document).on("click",".Changeimagetolarge",function(){
  var obj = $(this);
   obj.removeClass('Changeimagetolarge');
    obj.addClass('Changeimagetosmall');
   obj.next("img").attr('src',big_image);
  });
  
  
  $(document).on("click",".Changeimagetosmall",function(){
    var obj2 = $(this);
   obj2.removeClass('Changeimagetosmall');
    obj2.addClass('Changeimagetolarge');
   obj2.next("img").attr('src',small_image);
  });
  
  
  
  
  
});
```

```html
<script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div>

<button class="Changeimagetolarge">
Change Image
</button>
<img src="http://cdn4.sportngin.com/attachments/news_article/7560/0742/Screen_Shot_2017-01-04_at_11.30.31_AM_thumb.png">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input - however - all I am looking to do is replace the url src address so that the 'large' image is called.